# Symfony2 Doctrine blob type

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have legacy database that I am working with, which has binary column and stores some strings in it (I know that this is stupid, but I am not allowed to change that).
I had problem that those string in that blob are stored in 'UTF-16LE' charset, but I solved it by using php iconv function in my getter.

```
return iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $this->binstring);
```

Now the problem is that have doctrine annotation

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="colname", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
 private $binstring;
```

and the column type in database is "BINARY(40)" and when I use doctrine migrations or update schema directly it tryes to change that type to "VARCHAR" this is unwanted behavior and I would like to eliminate it. How could I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to use `blob` type instead of `string`? Also you can always implement new type http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using columnDefinition annotation

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column

Comment: I just tried it, and I gives me odd behavior for example if using doctrine migrations I diff my entities and database it generates: $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE db_table CHANGE COLNAME COLNAME BINARY(40) DEFAULT NULL'); this query changes nothing in the database, which is good, but why it generates it then?

Comment: What version of doctrine are you using?

Comment: Read documentation carefully. It says that "However you should make careful use of this feature and the consequences. SchemaTool will not detect changes on the column correctly anymore if you use “columnDefinition”."

Comment: Offtopic but binary is not the same as char. They are not equal. In general  sorting of binary columns are faster because for characer based columns Mysql take care of collations and encodings.

Comment: Doctrine version I use is 2.4.7. I only need to ignore changes on that single column.

Comment: I think Mysql will ignore changes because there is no diff. I don't know the easy way to make doctrine ignore such modifications.